# Is it possible for the existence of absolutely non-interacting quantum fields?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, interactions, beyond-the-standard-model

Quantum fields that do not interact directly with each other interact through other fields. For example, all the fields of the Standard Model interact through the gravitational field, although, for example, the neutrino field does not directly interact with the electromagnetic field. But can there be fields that do not interact in any way, either directly or through an intermediary field?

Comment: We believe that all the matters should interact with others, because we have no other way to verify the existence, even the dark matter, we can not detect them, but they exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we consider theory without gravity, there can be indeed such fields. Nothing prevents one from adding simply a free theory part to the Lagrangian (like free scalar theory, fermions, $U(1)$ gauge theory without matter):
$$
\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2} \partial_\mu \phi \ \partial^\mu \phi, \
\bar{\psi} (i \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu - m) \psi, \ -\frac{1}{4} F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu} 
$$
The issue is, that existence of such terms would be **undetectable**. There is no way to probe existence of particles in these theories, because any detection requieres some kind of interaction.

However, if one takes in account General Relativity, any common field has to interact at least with the gravity (for the simpliest case of scalar field):
$$
\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2} g^{\mu \nu}\partial_\mu \phi \ \partial_\nu \phi 
$$
The aforementioned fields have a strees-energy tensor, which is the current for gravitational field.

Here I am not sure completely, but the example for non-interacting field has to be some field theory without a stress-energy tensor (topological field theory). As an example, one can consider **Chern-Simons** theory with the abelian gauge group:
$$
\mathcal{L} = A \wedge d A
$$
Or the **BF**-theory (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/BF-theory):
$$
\mathcal{L} = B \wedge d F
$$